# I get "Cannot call a class as a function" error when I use a class component as a custom header for another component using react-navigation-stack

Tags: react-native

This is my class component which I want to use a custom header for my food component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {styles} from './Food.Styled';

class FoodHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.icon}
            source={require('../../../../images/images.jpeg')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.foodTxt}>FOOD</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.botContainer}>
          <View style={styles.leftBotCont1}>
            <View style={styles.txtCont1}>
              <Text style={styles.txt1}>Monday</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.txt2Con}>
                <Text style={styles.txt2}> (Click to change)</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {/* <DateTimePicker
              isVisible={isDateTimePickerVisible}
              onConfirm={handleDatePicked}
              onCancel={hideDateTimePicker}
            /> */}
            </View>

            <View style={styles.txtCont2}>
              <Text style={styles.txt3}>October 28</Text>
              <Image
                style={styles.icon1}
                source={require('../../../../images/images.jpeg')}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.rightBotCont}>
            <Image
              style={styles.icon2}
              source={require('../../../../images/images.jpeg')}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default FoodHeader;
```

I am importing it and using it in a stackNavigator as a custom header for my another component.

```
import {Food} from './src/modules/food';
import {FoodHeader} from './src/modules/food/foodheader';

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Food: {
      screen: Food,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: FoodHeader,
      },
    },
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  },
);
```

But it gives "Cannot call a class as a function" error. When I do not use it as custom header I do not see the error anymore but of course I do not see the header either in my food component.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this inside header :`<FoodHeader />`

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(

{
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Food: {
      screen: Food,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: <FoodHeader /> 
      },
    },
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I cannot believe I did not think of that. Appreciate it.